# Sklearn only predicts one class while dataset is fairly balanced (±80/20 split)

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to come up with a way to check what are the most influential factors of a person not paying back a loan (defaulting). I have worked with the sklearn library quite intensively, but I feel like I am missing something quite trivial...

The dataframe looks like this:

```
0   7590-VHVEG  Female  Widowed Electronic check    Outstanding loan    52000   20550   108 0.099   288.205374  31126.180361    0   No  Employed    No  Dutch   No  0
1   5575-GNVDE  Male    Married Bank transfer   Other   42000   22370   48  0.083   549.272708  26365.089987    0   Yes Employed    No  Dutch   No  0
2   3668-QPYBK  Male    Registered partnership  Bank transfer   Study   44000   24320   25  0.087   1067.134272 26678.356802    0   No  Self-Employed   No  Dutch   No  0
```

The distribution of the "DefaultInd" column (target variable) is this:

```
0    0.835408
1    0.164592
Name: DefaultInd, dtype: float64
```

I have label encoded the data to make it look like this, :

```
CustomerID  Gender  MaritalStatus   PaymentMethod   SpendingTarget  EstimatedIncome CreditAmount    TermLoanMonths  YearlyInterestRate  MonthlyCharges  TotalAmountPayments CurrentLoans    SustainabilityIndicator EmploymentStatus    ExistingCustomer    Nationality BKR_Registration    DefaultInd
0   7590-VHVEG  0   4   2   2   52000   20550   108 0.099   288.205374  31126.180361    0   0   0   0   5   0   0
1   5575-GNVDE  1   1   0   1   42000   22370   48  0.083   549.272708  26365.089987    0   1   0   0   5   0   0
2   3668-QPYBK  1   2   0   4   44000   24320   25  0.087   1067.134272 26678.356802    0   0   2   0   5   0
```

After that I have removed NaNs and cleaned it up some more (removing capitalizion, punctuation etc)

After that, I try to run this cell:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

y = df['DefaultInd']
X = df.drop(['CustomerID','DefaultInd'],axis=1)
X = X.astype(float)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=42)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Which results in this:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.83      1.00      0.91      1073
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       213

    accuracy                           0.83      1286
   macro avg       0.42      0.50      0.45      1286
weighted avg       0.70      0.83      0.76      1286
```

As you can see, the "1" class does not get predicted 1 time, I am wondering whether or not this behaviour is to be expected (I think it is not). I tried to use `class_weightd =  ‘balanced’`, but that resulted in an average f1 score of 0.59 (instead of 0.76)

I feel like I am missing something, or is this kind of behaviour expected and should I rebalance the dataset before fitting? I feel like the division is not that skewed (±80/20), there should not be this big of a problem.

Any help would be more than appreciated :)

Comment: Two suggestions: in train_test_split add `stratify=y`; use `predict_proba` instead of `predict` and find an optimal threshold to select the 1 class.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I will try to do that :) If I am understanding correctly it is a trade off between precision and recall of the dominant class and of the "dominated" class?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!